# Specifying a directory for output with FORFILES

Tags: windows, cmd, forfiles

I have a parent directory with three subdirectories. Two subdirectories have files to be processed . Third directory is "frames".

Using FFMPEG, I want to extract a frame from each of the .mp4 files in the two subdirectories and store them in the directory "images" (in a peer folder "images")

```
forfiles /S /M *.mp4 /C "cmd /c ffmpeg -i @file -ss  00:00:07.000 -vf "transpose=1" -vframes 1 frames\frames@Fname.jpg"
```

The above command throws an error. If I remove "frames\" the code works but the images are stored in the same subfolder as the .mp4

Comment: probably you should use "/" instead of "\". Try "./frames/frames@Fname.jpg"

Comment: You could open up a Command Prompt window and enter `ForFiles /?`, then read the usage information. Within that content you should note that provision is made for special characters in the command line by using the hexadecimal code for the character, in `0xHH` format. In this case you can use `0x22` for a doublequote, i.e. `0x22transpose=10x22`, if you really believe that those doublequotes are required.

Comment: Why do you use `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe` on not using option `/D` instead of internal command `for` of Windows command processor? The unnecessary usage of `forfiles` instead of `for` makes this file processing just much more difficult and slower than using `for`. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the output help.`for /R %I in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg.exe -i "%I" -ss  00:00:07.000 -vf "transpose=1" -vframes 1 "frames\frames@%~nI.jpg"` is definitely easier and faster if there is already a subdirectory `frames` in current directory.

Comment: @Mofi, you would achieve the equivalent to the `forfiles` command line when replacing `"frames\frames@%~nI.jpg"` by `"%~dpIframes\frames@%~nI.jpg"`...

Comment: Even with the literal `"` replaced by `0x22` as suggested by @Compo `forfiles` may have issues with quotation, because the path/name-related `@`-variables are expanded with enclosing quotation marks that may be desturbing. Anyway, what exact error is thrown by `forfiles`?

Comment: @aschipfl You are 100% right. `forfiles.exe` makes the directory of the file the current directory on starting `cmd.exe`. But this raises one more question: Has each directory containing an .mp4 file a subdirectory `frames`? So best would be `for /R %I in (*.mp4) do @md "%~dpIframes" 2>nul & if exist "%~dpIframes\" ffmpeg.exe -i "%I" -ss 00:00:07.000 -vf "transpose=1" -vframes 1 "%~dpIframes\frames@%~nI.jpg"`. Then a directory `frames` is created in each directory of an .mp4 file with suppression of error output on directory existing already and with an extra directory exist check.